# Automatically create weekly sheets which then collaborate information to one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to google sheets (also to stackoverflow) and I am trying to help the small trades company I work for move away from paper documents!

Every week we print off a time card (for each project/job within the project/task within the job) for staff to fill out and we manually change dates and upload the weekly hours to a totals sheet. For a couple weeks now I have been trying different methods of pulling this information together in multiple sheets and automating the new weekly sheet for them to fill out online and I feel like I have been doing lots of little codes in sheets and with Apps script which aren't helping each other and I'm wondering if what I'm asking is a big ask or if it is possible.

Here is what I have so far:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EKlzvymd6s_zVL27BkjZ-2DHDvs_mRXA78pw7UfFbng/edit?usp=sharing

My idea is that you would duplicate the Template file for each new project, edit the project information in one sheet/form (Edit Sheet) and it would auto create and rename (by weekly date preferably ie Aug 22-Aug 28) the weekly 'Time Cards' as a new sheet from the template (Time Card Template) which you would fill out your hours on manually each day and that would then populate the Labour Totals sheet from the weekly totals. I would love to also be able to have a drop down in the Labour Totals sheet to be able to show each Staff's hours on the project as a whole with the default option being All Staff Hours. Is this possible? Am I on the right track? Do I need to simplify my ask? Create more sheets with info/less sheets with the info?

I appreciate any help/insight, I have been enjoying coding and templating but I cannot work out how to tie it all together!

Amy

Comment: My insight is that if you are a novice and you wish to help the company, then hire someone that is not a novice.  The jobs will get done quicker and work better and if you are strongly motivated to learn you can learn to code by reading online references and figure how the code works on your own.

Comment: See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Please try to share the current solution you are having problem to achieve what you want. Your sample file is context depend of your real problem. Try to isolate it in sample that is easier to follow by the community and clarify better your concrete problem.